# A cell's value is returning zero even though the value is calculated

Tags: excel, vba

Procedure 1 (UpdateSalesSheet) reads several Excel files and inserts the data into a sheet called Sales.  It then calls Procedure 2 (UpdateSalesSheetCellColors), which changes the cells' background color depending on the value on the Reports sheet.

When I run the code in debug mode, or Procedure 2 independently, the background colors are updated as expected.  If I run the code normally then the colors are not updated because the code below is not reading the value of the formula in the cell.

```
 'select the cell to apply color
  Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Cells(found, months + 1)
  rng.Select
```

I would really appreciate your help!
Dave

```
Sub UpdateSalesSheet()
Dim spath, spath1, filename, productname, desc, modelnum, clr As String
Dim filecount, response As Integer
Dim dd As Single
Dim showwarning, dateentered As Boolean


'This routine copies products from the Products sheet to the Sales sheet and then read the new month's sales files and enters the Unit Sold for each model #.

Dim salesmonthenddate, sFolder As String
Dim cel, rng, found As Range
'Dim found As Object
Dim result, x, productforecast, productforecasthigh, productforecastlow As Integer
Dim tblSalesUnitsSoldcolumn, tblSalesLastRow, qty, mm, yyyy As Integer
Dim fso As Object
Dim filedate As Date

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ReplaceUnitSoldFormulas

'confirm sales files are in the Sales folder.  if not, cancel the update.
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

spath = Range("PQ_Path_to_Sales_by_Customers").Text & "*.xlsx"
spath1 = Range("PQ_Path_to_Sales_by_Customers").Text

filename = Dir(spath)
filedate = Format(FileDateTime(Left(spath, Len(spath) - 6) & filename), "mm/dd/yyyy")

Do While filename <> ""
   filecount = filecount + 1
   filename = Dir()
   If filename <> "" Then
       If filedate <> Format(FileDateTime(Left(spath, Len(spath) - 6) & filename), "mm/dd/yyyy") Then
           showwarning = True
       End If
   End If
Loop

If showwarning = True Then
    result = MsgBox("There are files with different date stamps, which may indicate you are attempting to process an old file.  Please confirm you copied all of the current sales to the prescribed folder and then restart this process.  You can override this warning by clicking 'Yes'.  If you are unsure click 'No' and confirm you have the correct files in the Sales folder.", vbYesNo)
    If result = 7 Then
        End 'cancel execution
    End If
End If

If filecount < 2 Then
    MsgBox "No sales files were found in the " & spath & " folder.  Please copy the sales files to the prescribed folder and then restart this process."
    Exit Sub
End If

salesmonthenddate = InputBox("Enter the Sales Month End Date (mm/dd/yyyy):")

'confirm/convert to month end date
dateentered = IsDate(salesmonthenddate)

If dateentered = False Then
    MsgBox "You did not enter a valid date.  Please try again."
    Exit Sub
End If

    mm = Month(salesmonthenddate)
    yyyy = Year(salesmonthenddate)
    salesmonthenddate = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(salesmonthenddate, 0)
    salesmonthenddate = Format(salesmonthenddate, "m/d/yyyy")
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Missing Sales").Range("l2").Value = salesmonthenddate
    
    'confirm Sales were not already entered for the month entered
    Worksheets("Sales").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("month_end_date").Select
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> 0
        If ActiveCell.Value = salesmonthenddate Then
            MsgBox "One or more rows were found with sales for month ending:  " & salesmonthenddate & " The process will not allow duplicates to be created."
            Sheets("Sales").Select
            Range("A1").Select
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
        
    'get last row of Sales Table before new month's data is copied to it
    tblSalesLastRow = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Sales").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + 1
    tblSalesUnitsSoldcolumn = 6
    
    'Clear Last_Months_Sales table
    Range("Table_Last_Months_Sales").Clear
    
    'Refresh data from Power Queries
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    
    'Refresh Last Month Sales table using Power Query
    'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Last Months Sales").ListObjects("Table_Last_Months_Sales").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales by Customers").ListObjects("Table_Sales_by_Customers").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    DoEvents
        
    'Copy the Products to the Sales sheet if date > 0 and date is not blank
    Sheets("Products").Select
                
    'Write new records
    Range("A2").Select
    Do While ActiveCell.Text <> ""
        'read row
        productname = ActiveCell.Text
        desc = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
        modelnum = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)
        clr = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)
        dd = Int(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5))
        
        If dd > 0 Then 'write row on Sales sheet
            Sheets("Sales").Select
            Range("A2").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.Value = productname
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = desc
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = modelnum
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = clr
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = salesmonthenddate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Formula = "=SUMIF('Last Months Sales'!$H$2:$H$200, [@[Model '#]] ,'Last Months Sales'!$I$2:$I$200)"
        End If
        
        Sheets("Products").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
        
    'Sort sales table so the current month is first (sort newest to oldest on Month End date and then Product alphabetically)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales").ListObjects("Sales").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales").ListObjects("Sales").Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range("Sales[Month End Date]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales").ListObjects("Sales").Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range("Sales[Product]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending _
        , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales").ListObjects("Sales").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
    'confirm/create sales backup folder and move processed files into folder
    sFolder = Worksheets("Control").Range("PathToBackupFolder") & "Sales " & yyyy & "-" & Format(mm, "00")
    If Len(Dir(sFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir sFolder
    End If
    
    fso.copyfile spath1 & "*.*", Range("PathToBackupFolder") & "Sales " & yyyy & "-" & Format(mm, "00")
    Set fso = Nothing
    
response = MsgBox("Sales from " & salesmonthenddate & " were imported.  Click <Yes> to update the cells colors on the Reports sheet.  Click <No> if you want to return to the Summary sheet.", vbYesNo)

startmonth = mm

If response = 6 Then
    startmonth = mm
    UpdateSalesSheetCellColors
ElseIf response = 7 Then
    Worksheets("Summary").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
End If
  
End Sub





Sub UpdateSalesSheetCellColors()
Dim months, beginmonth, endmonth, productforecast, productforecastlow, productforecasthigh, found, productyear As Integer
Dim productname As String
Dim my_cell As String
Dim cell_row, cell_col As Integer
Dim rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'update Report sheet cell colors
Worksheets("Reports").Select
Range("A1").Select

If startmonth = 99 Then
    beginmonth = 1
    endmonth = 12
Else
    beginmonth = startmonth
    endmonth = startmonth
End If

productyear = Range("ProductYear").Text
Range("ProductYearFirstProduct").Select
    
Do While ActiveCell.Text <> ""
    DoEvents
    productname = ActiveCell.Text
    For months = beginmonth To endmonth
        
        Worksheets("Forecast").Select
        'get forecast value for the product/month
        productforecast = WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Forecast").Range(Cells(2, months + 2), Cells(500, months + 2)), WorksheetFunction.Match(productname & productyear, Worksheets("Forecast").Range("P2:P500"), 0))
        productforecastlow = (1 - Worksheets("Control").Range("G2")) * productforecast
        productforecasthigh = (1 + Worksheets("Control").Range("G2")) * productforecast
        
        Worksheets("Reports").Select
        'find product name row
        Range("ProductYearFirstProduct").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
  
        Selection.Find(What:=productname, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext _
        , MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        
        found = ActiveCell.Row
                    
        'select the cell to apply color
        Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Cells(found, months + 1)
        rng.Select
                       
        'apply cell background - green, red or no fill
        If ((rng.Value > 0) And (rng.Value >= productforecasthigh)) Then
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 5287936
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        ElseIf ((rng.Value > 0) And (rng.Value <= productforecastlow)) Then
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 255
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Else 'no background color
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlNone
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
        
    Next months
            
    Worksheets("Reports").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Select
    
Loop
    
my_cell = Range("ProductYear").Address
cell_row = Range(my_cell).Row
cell_col = Range(my_cell).Column

'moves to the top left corner
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-9999
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Up:=-99999

'moves to active cell
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = cell_row
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = cell_col

'selects cell
Range(my_cell).Select
DoEvents

startmonth = 99
MsgBox "The Sales sheet's colors were updated."
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    

End Sub
```

Comment: Insufficient Information. No code for `Procedure 1`.  I'll guess you either have a typo from not using `Option Explicit` or your active sheet/cell is not what you think it is. You should explicitly declare the workbook/worksheet/cell. See [How to avoid using Select in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Did you post your code twice?

Comment: Yes, somehow the question is posted twice.

Comment: Hi, I added the option explicit and removed the select where possible and the same 2 lines of code do not return the cell's value in a normal run of the code, but does work perfectly in a debug mode.  I added a debug.print to confirm I am correct (it still does not work).  Frankly, I don't know how you want to me select a cell without using Select.  I would be more than happy to share the first procedure with you

Comment: How can I share procedure 1 with you?

Comment: Share procedure 1 by editing your question to include it.  And I don't understand why you think I want you to select a cell. It is YOU that seems to want to select a cell, and there is almost never a reason to do that.

Comment: Hi, I uploaded the both procedures for your review.  Please let me know if you need any other information.  Thank you.

Comment: The code you provided shows **none** of the changes I recommended nor those recommended in the linked question. Amongst other problems, there is no `Option Explicit`; there are undeclared variables (and possibly typos); there are multiple instances of `Select`, `Selection` and references to `Active Cells, workbook, Sheet` (either explicit or implicit) and at least one undefined `Sub or Function`.  As outlined in some of the answers in the link I provided above, this type of structure can cause multiple problems of the kind you are experiencing.

Comment: In addition to the above, although probably not contributing to your stated error, when you declare multiple variables on a single line (as you do), you need to state the type of **each** variable. Else they will take the `Variant` type. eg: **NOT** `Dim showwarning, dateentered As Boolean`. Should be `Dim showwarning as Boolean, dateentered As Boolean`. Also, using the `Integer` type is problematic, especially for `Rows` where the number of rows can well exceed the limit of an `Integer` type. Use `Long` instead.